# How should i solve a problem with needing to call this() and super() at the same time?

Tags: java, constructor, class-structure

Okay, so, I have a kind of specific problem. I have a class structure similar to this (simplified for simplicity purposes).

```java
class A {
    A() {
        // long initialization
    }

    A(int someValue) {
        this();
        // do something with someValue
    }
}

class B extends A {
    B() {
        super();
        // some long initialization
    }

    B(int someValue) {
        // What should i do here ?
    }
}
```

But now, i want to be able to construct class `B` using the second constructor. But the second constructor should call the `super(someValue)` constructor to make use of the `someValue` parameter, but at the same time it needs to call `this()` to to not have to duplicate the initialization of this class. The problem is that i can't call `this` and `super` constructors at the same time.

Also I can't extract the initialization in first constructor to some method, because I have some `final` fields that needs to be initialized inside the constructor to stay `final`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual solution is to flip the dependencies between your constructor: call `super(someValue)` inside `B(int someValue)`, and call `this(DEFAULT)` inside `B()`. However, you’ll need to figure out a valid `DEFAULT` for this case — that is, a default value for `someValue` that can be used by the parameter-less `B()` constructor (`null` often works).

If `A()` and `A(int someValue)` do fundamentally different things this won’t work, but that’s a sign that the class `A` is probably poorly designed (in other words: it *should* be feasible).

As an alternative, just have both `B()` and `B(int someValue)` call a method that performs the rest of the initialisation, after calling `super()`/`super(someValue)`.